# MySQL: Can't get LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: php, mysql, fuelphp

I'm creating an application using FuelPHP framework and MySQL and I'm trying to AJAX-update/insert a new log for an item already in DB.
This is my MySQL code:

```
UPDATE `work_orders` SET `status_id`='{$status}' WHERE `id` = '{$wo_id}';
INSERT INTO `work_order_logs`(`id`, `work_order_id`, `log_text`, `status_id`) VALUES ('{$id}', '{$wo_id}', '{$text}', '{$status}')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `log_text`='{$text}',`status_id`='{$status}';

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id;
```

When this code is executed from phpmyadmin it runs successfully and returns the id, however when executed from FuelPHP it only returns `1`, which I assume means a successful operation.

The FuelPHP code:

```
public static function updateLogById($id, $wo_id, $text, $status)
{
    try {
        $log_query = \DB::query("
            UPDATE `work_orders` SET `status_id`='{$status}' WHERE `id` = '{$wo_id}';
            INSERT INTO `work_order_logs`(`id`, `work_order_id`, `log_text`, `status_id`) VALUES ('{$id}', '{$wo_id}', '{$text}', '{$status}')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `log_text`='{$text}',`status_id`='{$status}';

            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id;
        ")->execute();
    } catch(\Database_Exception $e) {       
        return array(false, \DBE::handle_error());
    }
    return array(true, $log_query);
}
```

Can anybody see, what's wrong?
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: i think the problem is that you try an ``update`` and ``select`` within the same query

Comment: Put each statement in a separate query/command..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

separate the insert from the update that will fix it

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the right result you'll have to supply the query type in this case because it's not designed to do super smart result type detection based on the query. I think your query should work when you supply the following second parameter:

```
$result = \DB::query($query, \DB::SELECT);
```

This should give you a Result object from which you can get the id.